# What to add to my sbt to support Docker image creation for non-play project?

Tags: scala, docker, sbt

I have a regular project (not play) and I want to create docker image for this project....how can I do it?

I tried something like this:

```
dockerRepository := Some("docker-docker-local.artifactoryonline.com")

dockerUpdateLatest := true

dockerEntrypoint := Seq("bin/%s" format executableScriptName.value, "-J-Xms1024M", "-J-Xmx2048m", "-J-server")
```

but `dockerRepository`,`dockerUpdateLatest` and `dockerEntrypoint` are not familiare in my proj, I need to import something but I dont know what.

I also have a jfrog account to save my artifactory (this is why I added the url).

What is the best way to do it?

thanksss!@

Comment: have a look at http://rtfpessoa.xyz/when-scala-meets-docker/ it may be useful

Comment: http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/docker.html

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add an sbt plugin that supports Docker image creation to your build. Check out [sbt-native-packager](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/). To use it, add it to your `project/plugins.sbt`

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.0.6")
```

Then in your `build.sbt`, enable Docker support

```
enablePlugins(DockerPlugin)
```

After that, your settings should be recognized, and you have the following tasks available:

```
docker:publishLocal
```

Build a Docker image

```
docker:publish
```

Build image and publish to configured repository

See the full documentation at http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/ and http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/docker.html

There's also a mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!forum/sbt-native-packager